# Unix shell script - variable substitution inside another and concatenate values to the same variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables, unix

I have the below requirement to concatenate the value of a variable to its own variable and create one array:

```
Table=CRS
Job=JOBNAME
gen_job_$Table=GENERATEDJOB
gen_job_$TABLE=$Job,${gen_job_${Table}}
echo ${gen_job_${Table}} should give JOBNAME,GENERATEDJOB
```

I tried using the `eval` function also as below:

```
eval gen_job_$Table=$job,eval echo \$gen_job_$Table
```

However, I am not able to display the final result.

Comment: In the line `gen_job_$Table=GENERATEDJOB`, are you using a dollar sign inside a variable name? I don't actually know if that's valid. I tried it, and was given an error.

Comment: You can do something similar with *indirection*, e.g. `var1=10; a=1; str=var$a; echo ${!str}` Output is `10`

Answer (score 1):

You perhaps just want to consider using an array for a situation like this (and I recommend reading [this page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006), however, if you want to dynamically build your variable names it is possible.  To set a variable whose name is stored in another variable use `printf -v` like

```
table=CRS
job=JOBNAME
holds_name="gen_job_$Table"
printf -v "$holds_name" 'GENERATEDJOB'
```

Then when you want to access the variable whose name is set in `holds_name` you can use indirection:

```
printf '%s,%s\n' "$job" "${!holds_name}"
```

Using braces around the variable name, if the first character inside the brace is `!` then the rest of the word is treated as the name of a variable that is expanded to find the name of the actual variable whose value should be used.